# Dynamically updating the condition while indexing and selecting data in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

While selecting data from a dataframe I need to do in such a way that the condition changes according to the length of the input list. This is my current code. The first element in the list is the name of the column and the second element is the value of the column.

```
import pandas as pd

list_1 = [('a', 2), ('b', 5)]
list_2 = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], [2, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


def select_data(l, dataset):
    df = None
    i = len(l)
    if i == 2:
        df = dataset[(dataset[l[0][0]] == l[0][1]) & (dataset[l[1][0]] == l[1][1])]

    if i == 3:
        df = dataset[(dataset[l[0][0]] == l[0][1]) & (dataset[l[1][0]] == l[1][1]) & (dataset[l[2][0]] == l[2][1])]

    return df


print(select_data(list_1, data))
print(select_data(list_2, data))
```

There must be a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: What is `dataset` ?

Comment: `return dataset[dataset.iloc[:i,0].eq(dataset.iloc[:i,1]).all()]`?

Comment: @AlexandreB. It is just a dataframe. I have made changes in the question please take a look.

Comment: @BiratBadeShrestham post the expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest This code gives the expected output. I just want to optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short filtering with *`Dataframe.loc[<filtering_mask>, :]`* approach:

```
In [150]: data
Out[150]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  1  1
3  2  5  6

In [151]: def select_data(filter_lst, df):
     ...:     d = dict(filter_lst)
     ...:     res = df.loc[(df[list(d.keys())] == pd.Series(d)).all(axis=1)]
     ...:     return res
     ...: 
     ...: 

In [152]: select_data(list_1, data)
Out[152]: 
   a  b  c
3  2  5  6

In [153]: select_data(list_2, data)
Out[153]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create dynamic condition. To do, you can write the condition in a `string` format and then evaluate it with the `eval` function. To do so, you also need to know the `dataset` name.

Here the code assuming all the keys are in the given dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

input1 = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
# input2 = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]   # Same output as for input1 for the below dataset

dataset = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], [
                       2, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


def create_query_condition(list_tuple, df_name):
    """ Create a string condition from the keys and values in list_
    Arguments:
        :param list_tuple: 2D array: 1st column is key, 2nd column is value
        :param df_name: dataframe name
    """
    my_array = np.array(list_tuple)
    # Get keys - values
    keys = my_array[:, 0]
    values = my_array[:, 1]
    # Create string query
    query = ' & '.join(['({0}.{1} == {2})'.format(df_name, k, v)
                        for k, v in zip(keys, values)])
    return query


query = create_query_condition(input1, 'dataset')
print(query)
# (dataset.a == 1) & (dataset.b == 2)
print(dataset[eval(query)])
#    a  b  c
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  1  2  3
```

Comment: I didn't know about the eval function. You sir are a true hero.

Comment: @BiratBadeShrestha, `eval` is never be a safe approach!

Comment: @BiratBadeShrestha I agree with you if you do not trust the input or what you are running. But in this situation, I'm curious to know what can make `eval` unsafe ?

Comment: @AlexandreB., *if you do not trust the input* - ideally you should not ever trust the external input. Those simple lists are just static samples.